# reducing framework-version on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a solution with different projects all on Framework 4.5.2

Now on the target system this framework isn't installed. So I needed to change the target to 4.5.,. what I did.
After rebuilding and publishing the web project I receive the follwoing error:

> The compiler failed with error code -2146232576.

which is thrown from .\bin\rocelyn\csc.exe

The web.config has the correct target framework, but I can see there are entries in the packages.config that still have the wrong framework:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MimeTypeMap.List" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

I **guess** these packages cause the problem. What can be done about that?

Comment: What's your Roslyn compiler version? If you are using Roslyn compiler 2.0+, you need to install .net framework 4.6+ on your server.

Comment: Installing 4.6xx was not an option. (Server not maintained by me). But as I wrote in my answer, I found a sokution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by reinstalling the nuget-packages after lowering the Framework-version:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

This dropped the 4.5.2 - packages and reinstalled the 4.5 - packages